# CSS for background on anchor hover?

Tags: html, css

Please view my current page here: http://shrineweb.in/other-files/other/showyourskills-responsive-certsplan/index.html

And what I want to achieve is: http://shrineweb.in/other-files/other/showyourskills-responsive-certsplan/Home-nav.jpg

I tried to accomplish this with a:hover and putting background as white color and a fixed background image of blue color on bottom repeating x. But its not working.

Markup:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/home.png" alt="Home Icon"></a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bundle</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Faqs</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul
{
list-style:none;}

nav ul li
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 38px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

nav ul li a
{
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #2a323a;
}

nav ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(../img/hover-bg_05.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: All you have to do is remove 4px bottom padding on anchor add 4px bottom border on both states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 38px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2a323a;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: solid 7px #CCC;
}



nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url("http://shrineweb.in/other-files/other/showyourskills-responsive-certsplan/css/../img/hover-bg_05.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: bottom;
  border-bottom: solid 7px blue;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the bottom blue line is still not appearing. I have updated on my link.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But I also want that effect on active link (in addition to hover.) I tried adding same styling to `nav ul li a:active` but it didn't work.

Comment: ul li a.active {border-bottom: solid 7px blue !important;}

Comment: it didn't work. Please check live link. Any other suggestion?

Comment: ul li a:active {background-color: #ffffff; border-bottom: solid 5px #DD4700 !important;}

Comment: Still not working. Also, do you know why the navigation is not aligning at top?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to use short hand properties, this is a good practice and as well a less line of code will help to reduce the file size also.

Check the ***[Demo](http://jsbin.com/gogugalo/2/)***.

```
nav ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color:#F6F6F6;
}

nav ul li
{
display: block;
float: left;
padding:25px 20px;
border-bottom:4px solid #DDDDDD;
}

nav ul li a
{
font: 400 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #2a323a;
}

nav ul li:hover
{
background-color: #ffffff;
/*background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url(../img/hover-bg_05.png);*/
border-bottom:4px solid #3DA6DC;
}
.current
{
  border-bottom:4px solid #3DA6DC;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

and using this small jquery code you can active the class.

```
$("li").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("current");
  $("li").not(this).removeClass("current");
});
```